# to save form data on BUTTON click into database + php+ mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

how to save form data into database on simple BUTTON click ?
and store the data into a session variable on BUTTON click ?
is it possible ? i dont want submit button.
Thanks in advice.please reply as soon as possible..i have done searching over google whole day ,didnt got any solution till yet.
please reply me

Comment: Be specific, and should share your code of what you tried(if)

Comment: You can use Ajax for this. You don't have a postback but you can store data while the user doesn't notice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX for that or use the `form.submit()` property. 
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

```
<form name="postForm" action="post.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<button onclick="javascript: submitform();" value="Click me" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.postForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have form field campaign name,image description ,title ..i have to save it in database on button click...

Comment: You can save it in the database in the `post.php` script or whatever script you are posting your form to. You can access all the form input in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays, depending on weather you are using `GET` or `POST` to submit the form.

Comment: i have used a php script campaign_basic.php where i have written queries to insert the data into the database.but m not getting anything in $_POST[] on button click.its working when i used a submit button but i want to do it on BUTTON click

Comment: Can you put your code for your FORM and also the code of your campaign_basic.php ?

Comment: <form name="campaign-basic" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Small Image</td>
<td><input type="file" name="small_image"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category</td>
<td>
<select name='category' id='category'>
<?php
while($rowcategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultcategories))
{        
?>
<option value='<?php echo $rowcategories['cat_name'];?>'><?php echo $rowcategories['cat_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>  
</td>
</tr>

Comment: <tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td><input type="text" name="title"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Short Description</td>
<td><textarea  name="short-description" cols="15" rows="5"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Campaign-Link</td>
<td><input type="text" name="campaign-link"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><input type="button" name="save" value="Save"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

Comment: if(isset($_POST['save']))
{

    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $short_desc = $_POST['short-description'];
    $campaign_link = $_POST['campaign-link'];
 // insert into campaign details 
    $result = $ocamp->insertCampaignBasics($cat_id,$title,$short_desc,$campaign_link,$ch_id);} campaign_basic.php

Comment: Please update your question with the code.